# Plotting confidence interval - graph showing odd results

Tags: anova, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization

Just wondering if anyone can help me analyse the following:

I plotted my confidence intervals from a GLM, and found that a lot of the points don't overlap the C.I.

What exactly does this mean usually?

For reference I did an experiment to test how temperature impacted DNA concentration over time.

Y = concentration

x = time in hours

[image]

Comment: What precisely are you plotting? If the dots are estimated group means and the CIs are CIs for estimated group means, then the estimates should usually lie within the CIs. So it looks like something is broken.

Comment: Hi Stephan, 
I'm plotting the response to three different treatments over time. 
I.e. measuring how three different temperatures impact the concentration of DNA (Y) over time (X)
If the estimates do not lie in the CI, does this mean I may have the wrong model?

Comment: Do the dots represent a single measurement each? Or are they averages over multiple measurements, or estimates of group means?

Comment: Sorry Stephan, i misread your question. The dots represent averages over multiple measurements.

Comment: Thanks. This looks very strange indeed. Estimates falling outside their CIs can happen in exceptional cases, but it shouldn't happen as often as here. Unfortunately, I don't think we can be very helpful without knowing your specific data and model. You could edit your post to include this information, but then it might get so long and unwieldy that people might not even read it...

Comment: Thanks Stephan. You're probably correct there.
From your knowledge, does estimates falling outside their CIs usually relate to the data itself? I.e. the means? Or is it a bit of a case by case basis?

Comment: Well, if this is actually a thing (as opposed to, say, a coding error, which I would still assume a more likely explanation), then it must come from the data "in some way". It may be a consequence of a model that simply doesn't conform to the observations very well.